# Mysql percentage

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, percentage

I have a table with some sales data, there is a sales columns for European, Japan, other sales and North America,

My question is how do I work out what percentage of sales occurred in North America?

This is my first time posting so apologies if the post is not great

Comment: Get the north america sales and divide by the total ones.

Comment: The same way you would calculate any other percentage. Divide the North America sales by the total sales.

Comment: for a good posting: sample data, expected results and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I took MYSQL out of the equation and just used maths to work out the answer then it become easy to implement into MSQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(NORAMERICA) /( Country1 + country2 + country3) as %North America  from Sales
```